Uso y buenas practicas de los archivos .h en C
Espero estén todos bien. Quería consultar acerca de los archivos .h y .c en C. Como dice el título, sus buenas practicas y correcto uso. Además voy a poner un código de ejemplo que si bien anda, no se si esta del todo bien el uso de los archivos .h y .c. Si me podrían corregir me hacen un favor.
Primero tengo un .h que es:
#ifndef MANEJO_ARCHIVO_H
#define MANEJO_ARCHIVO_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTES_A_CONSUMIR 100
// Uso 100 bytes a consumir, ya que ninguna de las palabras inecesarias que se debe consumir supera
// esa cantidad. Y en caso de cambiar el formato se cambia solo un numero.

typedef struct{
    int f; // f representa las filas y c las columnas, esto es (f,c)
    int c; 
} Posicion;

typedef struct{
    int dimension;
    int obs_aleatorios;
    Posicion posicion_inicial;
    Posicion objetivo;
    Posicion* obs_fijos; // En este puntero guardaré los obstaculos fijos que haya.
    int tamaño_obs_fijos; // Este es el tamaño de el anterior puntero.
} Datos_Laberinto;

int lee_dimension_o_aleatorios(FILE*);
void carga_obs_fijos(FILE*, Posicion *, int*);
Posicion carga_posicion(FILE * );
void carga_datos(Datos_Laberinto * , FILE * );

#endif // MANEJO_ARCHIVO_H

Luego su correspondiente .c empieza con:
#include "manejo_archivo.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Resto de funciones

Ahora tengo otro .h que es:
#ifndef CREA_LABERINTO_H
#define CREA_LABERINTO_H

#include "manejo_archivo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

char** inicializa_laberinto(int );
void carga_ceros(char** , int );
void coloca_obs_fijos(Posicion* , char** , int );
void carga_objetivo_inicial(Posicion , char** , int );
void coloca_obs_aleatorios(char** , int , int );
void carga_archivo_salida(FILE* , char** , int );

#endif // CREA_LABERINTO_H

Que su .c tiene:
#include "crea_laberinto.h"
#include "manejo_archivo.h" // Lo incluyo por la definicion de las estructuras.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Resto del codigo

Finalmente en el main:
#include "crea_laberinto.h"
#include "manejo_archivo.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Resto de codigo

De estos códigos me parecen raras la inclusión de stdio en los .h. Luego el tener que incluir manejo_archivo.h para incluir la estructura posición, los #define MANEJO_ARCHIVO_H y el análogo de crea_laberinto.h y bueno, ustedes me sabrán decir si están mal o es normal, cualquier otra cosa que noten extraña me corrigen. Desde ya muchas gracias.

El código se ve bien y lo estás guardando correctamente. Más que buenas prácticas parece que quisieras preguntar por qué define una macro. A eso de le llama include guard y el propósito es evitar que un mismo archivo se incluya 2 veces. Estoy seguro de que ya debe haber una pregunta al respecto.

Okey genial Mateo, muchas gracias por responder! Voy a averiguar del include guard mejor, vi el término pero me falta un poco más el concepto. Y te pregunto, si yo incluyo stdio en el .h no debería poder obviarlo en los .c correspondientes?

Si, muchas veces sucede que un archivo se incluye transitivamente: uno de los archivos que incluiste ya incluyen ese archivo. No debería ser necesario incluir stdio.h si ya incluyes manejo_archivo.h

Listo, muchisimas gracias Mateo! Saludos y buen finde.
